# Can I 'Discard changes' (revert file delete) in git/sourcetree after having removed my repo access?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have revoked read/write/admin access to GIT repository of my friend. I also deleted the .c files of code from his disk, but I didnt remove /.git directory, etc. He is on Windows.
He also still has most of the repo files, the resources, the git cache, gitignnore, I only removed code .c files
Will he be able to use his local git cache to restore the code files?

Comment: If he has the .git folder intact then he can recover it, given you didn't wipe his history.

Comment: Which file from .git folder has that backup data?

Answer (score 0):

If you removed some files, say, accidentally from a local, you can get everything back with `git checkout HEAD -- .` or the one that has to be used with caution `git reset --hard`. As long as the repo information is fine, you can get files back.